# Boyle's law ( Volume and Pressure )

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, volume

I am confused about the fact that (The volume is inversely proportional to the pressure)
I understand that when the atmospheric pressure increases the volume of our object decreases.

But why should it be proportional?
Why when or pressure is doubled our volume becomes $\frac{1}{2}$
Why not $\frac{1}{4}$

Is there any way we can prove this
Cause I have this same problem with other formulae. Also I have a problem with understanding proportionality.

Comment: Boyle's law, like some other thermodynamic laws of its time, were derived *experimentally* first.

Comment: On the theory side, the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) is derived [here](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/lets-derive-the-ideal-gas-law-from-scratch-efb1b5490d67). (Many advanced topics are involved, but the broad strategy may be of interest to read through.) At constant temperature, we recover [Boyle's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law).

Comment: Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

From observation, Boyle observed that the product of pressure and volume of a gas was nearly constant when the temperature was held constant. What he was observing was the behavior of a nearly ideal gas.

The equation for an ideal gas in equilibrium is

$$PV=nRT$$

For a fixed number of moles $n$ and fixed temperature $T$ where $R$ is the universal gas constant, we see that the product of pressure and volume is exactly constant. Equivalently, pressure and volume are inversely proportional to one another.

Hope this helps.